# Async Custom Validation at Ionic3

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, ionic3

I want to check availability of email or the registered email cannot be submitted any more. The scenario: user types email in form then system checks if in database the email was already saved then system triggers error. I tried to display the result that if "count > 0" then the output is true so that return object "{is_notavail: true}". However, in template "is_notavail" always return "false". Strangely, form color is red neither I submit new nor saved email.  These are my codes.

email.ts (validator)

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


export class EmailValidator{
    static userService: UserServiceProvider;
    constructor(userService: UserServiceProvider){
        EmailValidator.userService = userService;
    }
    checkEmailAvail(control: FormControl){
    return EmailValidator.userService.isExist(control.value).toPromise().then(count => {
        if(count>0){
            return {is_notavail: true};
        }else return null;
    });

    }

}
```

user-service.ts (service)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";


@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  private _users: BehaviorSubject<User[]>;
  private baseUrl: string;
  private dataStore: {
    users: User[]
  };
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.baseUrl = 'api/v1/user';
    this.dataStore = {users: []};
    this._users = <BehaviorSubject<User[]>> new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this.users = this._users.asObservable();
  }

  isExist(email: string){  
      return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/isexist', {'email': email}).map(data => data.json().data);
  }
}
```

register.ts (pages)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, Loading, AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";
import { PasswordValidator } from '../../validators/password/password';
import { EmailValidator } from "../../validators/email/email";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-register',
  templateUrl: 'register.html',
})

export class RegisterPage {
  submitAttempt: boolean = false;  
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  control: FormControl;
  _isNotAvail: boolean = false;
  loading: Loading;
  user: User = {name: '', email: '', password: ''};
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
    private userServiceProvider: UserServiceProvider,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email, (new EmailValidator(this.userServiceProvider)).checkEmailAvail])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
      confPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    }, {
      validator: PasswordValidator.confPassword('password', 'confPassword')
    });

  }
}
```

register.html

```
     <ion-item *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').errors && registerForm.get('email').dirty">
        <p *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('required')">Email harus diisi.</p>
        <p *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('email')">Email tidak sesuai format.</p>
        <p *ngIf="registerForm.get('email').hasError('is_notavail')">Email sudah terdaftar.</p>
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Validators and AsyncValidators. If you are making a request to the server you should make this an AsyncValidator. To do that, provider the validator in an array in the 3rd parameter.

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], [new EmailValidator(this.userServiceProvider).checkEmailAvail]],
```

Also I noticed in the EmailValidator constructor you set the `userServiceProvider` as a static property on EmailValidator. I assume you are doing this because `userServiceProvider` is undefined when the checkEmailAvail validator function runs. This is because it's running with the scope of the caller. Make the userServiceProvider an instance property (instead of a static property) and pass the function like this-

```
var emailValidator = new EmailValidator(this.userServiceProvider);
```

.

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email], [emailValidator.checkEmailAvail.bind(emailValidator)]],
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was solved. I add comment below to elaborate the issue

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Micah. I explain my problem in deep. Actually, there are two mistakes.

The first I was wrong put AsyncValidation in second  param instead of third param, you fix my code, this is the right one:

```
let emailValidator = new EmailValidator(this.userService);
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['',  Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email]), emailValidator.checkEmailAvail.bind(emailValidator)],
  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])],
  confPassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
}, {
  validator: PasswordValidator.confPassword('password', 'confPassword')
});
```

The second my validator should be promise and uses resolve

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';

export class EmailValidator{
    static userService: UserServiceProvider;
    constructor(userService: UserServiceProvider){
        EmailValidator.userService = userService;
    }
    checkEmailAvail(control: FormControl){
    return new Promise ( resolve => {
            EmailValidator.userService.isExist(control.value).subscribe(count => {
                if(count>0){                  
                    return resolve({is_notavail: true});
                }else {
                return resolve(null);
                }

    })
    })
}
}
```